# Clearing a ListView: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I'm having some trouble with something that should be really simple.  I can't clear my list view when there is an item selected.

```
ItemListView.Items.Clear()

For i As Integer = SExp.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim MyItem As New ListViewItem
    MyItem.Content = SExp(i).dtDateTime.ToString
    ItemListView.Items.Add(MyItem)
Next

ItemListView.SelectedItem = 0
```

That code is part of the code in a button call -- it clears whatever is in the list view and repopulates the listview with dates from a struct.

It works great when nothing is selected, but I get the "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error when something is selected.

I've tried many things, including removing each item in the listivew one-by-one with a for loop -- I get an error when it hits the selected item.  I have also tried to deselect the item and then clear, but I've been unable to do that as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that the snippet you have in your button click event? Try checking for bounds before `ItemListView.SelectedItem = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.  I had a SelectionChanged event that was firing when I cleared the listview, and the event couldn't handle an index of "-1" (no selection).  Since I didn't have a breakpoint in the SelectionChanged event, I didn't realize that the error was actually being thrown there.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You saved me from many more hours of struggling to understand why such a thing happens with the totally wrong exception details that C# provides in such case!

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemListView.SelectedItem = 0
```

You don't have an item of '0,' you added datetimes.  Change it to

```
ItemListView.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: The problem isn't with ItemListView.SelectedItem = 0.  The error happens at ItemListView.Items.Clear()

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
DataSource = null;
DataBind();
```